# Parsing error: The keyword 'yield' is reserved

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, gulp

I am using typescript and gulp.

i am using below task for compiling my typescript

```
gulp.task('compile', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/**/**/*.*')
        .pipe(ts({
            "target": "ES5",
            "module": "system",
            "isolatedModules": true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('functions'));
    });
```

Typescript code is

```
async welcomeIntent() {
        this.app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv,input) => {
            conv.ask('<speak>Welcome Intent<break time="1"/> </speak>');
            let  output;
            output  =   await this.entryService.getTodaysEntryOfUser(conv);
            output.then((todaysEntry) => {
                let question:Question =  this.testService.getStartQuestion(1);
                                    return;
            })
            .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting document', err);
            });

          });
```

The Promise implemented Typescript function

```
public getTodaysEntryOfUser(conv: any): Promise<any> {
           let documentDetail;
           let  self    =   this;
           let subjectId    =   conv.request.user.userId;
           let questionID   =   conv.request.user.questionID;
           let docRef=  this.dbManager.collection('Question');
           console.log("docRef-------------->",docRef);
           return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
             docRef.get().then(doc => {
                documentDetail  =   doc;
                conv.user.response= doc.data();
                console.log('Document data------>', doc.data());
                return resolve(doc.data());
                })
                .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting document', err);
                reject(err);
                });

            });
        }
```

After compiling from typescript to JS, The code of the JS method is

```
IntentService.prototype.welcome= function () {
                    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
                        var _this = this;
                        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
                            this.app.intent('test', function (conv, input) {
                                conv.ask('<speak>Welcome Intent<break time="1"/> </speak>');
                                var output;
                                output = yield _this.testEntryService.getTodaysEntryOfUser(conv);
                                output.then(function (todaysEntry) {

                                    var question = _this.testService.getStartQuestion(1);

                                    return;
                                })["catch"](function (err) {
                                    console.log('Error getting document', err);
                                });
                            });
                            return [2 /*return*/];
                        });
                    });
                };
```

Generated JS code of Promise implemented functions

```
entryService.prototype.getTodaysEntryOfUser = function (conv) {
                    var documentDetail;
                    var self = this;
                    var subjectId = conv.request.user.userId;
                    var questionID = conv.request.user.questionID;
                    var docRef = this.dbManager.collection('Question');
                    console.log("docRef-------------->", docRef);
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
                            documentDetail = doc;
                            conv.user.response = doc.data();
                            console.log('Document data------>', doc.data());
                            return resolve(doc.data());
                        })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                            console.log('Error getting document', err);
                            reject(err);
                        });
                    });
                };
```

The error i am getting is

```
error  Parsing error: The keyword 'yield' is reserved
```

The issue here is keyword "Yield" is not commented. if i deploy using "firebase deploy --only functions" i am getting error. Yield keyword line should be  as below, i.e.., if i comment yield keyword, i am not getting error.

```
output = /*yield */ _this.entryService.getTodaysEntryOfUser(conv);
```

How to do this using gulp?

I referred link "https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html"

Here they specified, If we generate using "ES5" , the generate code will be with commented with "Yield"

Comment: Please also post your typescript input that's generating that js output - hard to diagnose without it

Comment: output  =   await this.entryService.getTodaysEntryOfUser(conv);

Comment: jmcgriz , i have updated with needed code.